# Animate sidebar outside from the content then back

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I have a website with switchable layouts. On the default one, the sidebar (aside) is normally right near the content with `float: right`. When I click to switch, the sidebar should animate to the right side of the browser window, smoothly. I've tried many ways, but I can't make it work perfectly.

Here is the fiddle with the current status: http://jsfiddle.net/kqzug20p/

As you see, after click the "Animate" button, the sidebar goes to left first, than animates to the right. 
Clicking the default just places the sidebar back without any animation...

Got any ideas where I did it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/jevgenig/kqzug20p/1/)

Generally, the problem is that this element does not have initial "right:" value.
And what jQuery's animation does - is increasing existing (initial) value to the target value.

I've added `right: 78px` to "aside" and removed `top:78px`.
Also, you can give pure integers to `.css()` method

CSS:

```
aside {
    float: right;
    right:78px;
```

JS:

```
$("aside").addClass("animate").animate({
        right: 0
    });
```

**UPDATED**

and here is update for Back animation:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jevgenig/kqzug20p/3/)

**UPDATE2**

Here is improved version: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jevgenig/kqzug20p/5/)

It has more complex logic, that is ready for different "main" sizes. It might not work for you for you 100%, but gives the idea about the direction

Comment: I need to animate the top value as well cause the website has a fixed header with the height of 78px.

Comment: Then just add "top:78px" to the "aside" css class, so it always remains 78px away from top

Comment: I see, it seems nice now! But the back (default) animation still missing. The aside just jumps back :(

Comment: problem is the right: 78px: I can't use fixed value, since the browser size depends on the user's resolution.

Comment: Ok, then we have to calculate it ... what shell we take as a correct right position? is it "section" (the grayed-out background rectangle) ?

Comment: basically the aside should move out from the section to the right edge of the main (browser window). I have no idea how we can calculate the right position without any problem :S

Comment: Try UPDATE2 version. It has more calculation logic.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I only need to make the top property look good as well and I'm finally done! :)